# Computing reciprocals of primes

Tags: number-theory

I was looking at the following video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmfxIhmGPP4
where I learnt that William Shanks was trying to compute the reciprocals of prime numbers and see after how many terms in the decimal place, it started repeating. For e.g. $1/11=0.090909...$ and it repeats after $2$ decimal places. In order to compute this for any prime $p$, one may create the multiplication table of $p$ and then keep dividing until repetition occurs.

However in the YouTube link, it was mentioned that Shanks probably was doing it using some other technique since all his errors were either his answer being double or half the original answer. Naturally I started wondering how one may go about doing it in order to make it easier and couldn't come up with anything fancy. Does anyone know what he actually did? Any other novel ideas will also make me happy.

Comment: The length of a period is always a divisor of p-1, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Fractions_with_prime_denominators

Comment: Hmmmmm, that explains the reason why mistakes can only be this type of mistakes. So he might not have had any other trick up his sleeve :(

Comment: Here is a link to the paper where Shanks explains his methods: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/112821.pdf The bibliographic information is On the Number of Figures in the Period of the Reciprocal of Every Prime Number
below 20,000, Proceedings of the Royal Society of London , 1873 - 1874, Vol. 22 (1873 - 1874), pp. 200-210.

Comment: General advice : Read wikipedia and pdf-articles , if you want to make progress in math. Youtube vidoes have another purpose : Entertaining the watchers. Of the many youtube videos about math I watched , there was ONE I found actually good : The video about Mandelbrod sets and the amazing pictures arising from it.

Comment: Had a look at that link, User?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry I needed more time to go through the technique since I got busy with some other work. Nice job digging up the work. I guess that answers everything.

Comment: Let me encourage you, when you've had a chance to work out what Shanks did, to write up your findings and post them as an answer.

Comment: I have to admit, the math described in the pdf attached is above me. I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I would have happily accepted your answer and upvoted it if you had written it. However, I do not get much time these days to help the society here. Luckily someone wrote a nice answer. So......  : )

Comment: All's well that ends well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if this helps, but the number of digits in the repeating expansion of $p$ is simply the smallest number $k$ such that the repeating number $999\ldots 99$ where there are $k$ $9$'s is divisible by $p$.

For instance in the case of $1/11$ we see that there are two repeating digits because $11\mid 99$. Note that the repeating number can also be represented as $10^k-1$, so we want $p\mid 10^k-1$, or $10^k\equiv 1$ (mod $p$). Now it is clear that the number $k$ we are looking for is simply order base $p$ of $10$, or ord$_p(10)$. Keep in mind that by Fermat's Little Theorem, $k$ has to divide $p-1$. Like in the case of $11$, where $2\mid 11-1=10$. So, we only have to look through the factors of $p-1$ to find our answer.

Here is an example of finding it for the number $59$:
So $59-1=58$, so we only need to look at $1, 2, 29$, and $58$. $10^1$ and $10^2$ clearly don't work, so we only need to figure out if $10^{29}$ works. $10^3=1000=56=-3$ and $10^{27}=(-3)^9=-19683=23$. And $23*100=-1$. So $10^{29}$ is $-1$ in mod $59$, meaning it doesn't work, so we know $1/59$ has $58$ repeating digits.

Comment: Nice explanation! Question: Where did 3 and 27 in your example come from?

Comment: @VictorResnov Let me try to help you out. So the reason that you were unable to follow the pdf is probably because you are not familiar with modular arithmetic. So when he writes $56=-3$ he means that $56$ and $-3$ leave the same remainder when divided by $59$. He could have also written $56=115$ in this manner.  The magic lies here that it is difficult to say, for e.g., the remainder of $115^4$ when divided by $59$ but since $115=-3$, the remainder is same as $(-3)^4$ when divided by $59$ and $(-3)^4=81=22$ when divided by $59$ and I could do this without calculator. Magic! XD

Comment: Oh yeah the 3 and 27 weren't from anything, I just needed to get 10^29 in modular 59. So I took 10^3, then put it to the power of 9 to get to 10^27, then multiplied by 100. I could just as well have took 10^4, put it to the power of 7 to get 10^28, then multiplied by 10. Or took 10^5, put it to the power of 5 to get 10^25, then multiply by 10000. Any way would give you the same. :)

Comment: This is a great response. You seem to employ similar results that Shanks claims to have used in his paper, though admittedly more concisely than Shanks explained them.